# Adding new users/accounts for SFMC SFTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp

According to the latest release notes we can now add up to three FTP users per MID:

> This release allows you to add up to three FTP accounts per MID.
>   Create or delete these users in the Setup section of your account on
>   your own. Restrict account access by specifying the IP addresses a
>   user can access the account from. This new feature gives you the
>   flexibility to assign different users to different business units as
>   needed.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_january_2020_platform_ftp_users.htm&type=5

But anytime I try to add new users the username is locked as the MID and it claims that this user already exists. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: This feature was delayed. Perhaps it will be released tonight. The ui will change

Comment: It was not released this week. Perhaps next week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Of Today(20 Feb,2020), I can confirm that this feature from January 2020 release is not released yet. I took a screen grab while validating this in the platform today.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, glad I'm not crazy then. Feel free to update your answer when the feature is released for anyone's future reference!